# Run commands on all the replicas of a service in docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm setup with 4 nodes and deployed Pumba in global mode to the swarm setup. After that, I have run my application containers on the swarm with replicas on different nodes. I want to send kill or netem command to all the Pumba containers in all the nodes.

Right now the only way I am able to do it is either by specifying the command when creating the service:

```
docker service create --name PUMBA --mode=global   --mount=type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock  gaiaadm/pumba:master pumba --random --interval 10s kill re2:"^customer-api*" --signal SIGTERM
```

Or by going in each host and doing a exec to the container and running the command:

```
 docker exec -i $(docker ps| grep pumba|cut -d 'g' -f1 ) pumba netem --duration 60s delay --time 3000  --jitter 40 --distribution normal re2:"^${name[i]}*" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I am creating a bash script for this. Is there a way I could pass the command to the service so that it's reflected in all of its global replicas?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send a new command to Pumba container using the following command

```
docker service update PUMBA --args "pumba --random --interval 5s kill re2:"^customer*" --signal SIGTERM"
```